# Creating a collection and get it in the browser console

Tags: meteor

I have created simple app:

> $ meteor create LendLib

and added a collection on the top of LendLib.js:

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
```

Now I launch Chrome browser and open console:

```
> lists 
ReferenceError: lists is not defined
> some = new Meteor.Collection("some"); 
Meteor.Collection {_makeNewID: function, _transform: null, _manager: Meteor._LivedataConnection, _collection: LocalCollection, _name: "some"…}
```

Why I cannot get my collection lists ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out they updated it in 0.6.0 to allow it to scope to the window object, so just remove the "var" part, so it's just "lists" and not "var lists". Worked for me.

Comment: I can create a collection from console (some = new Meteor.Collection("some");), so I think Mongo is working....